# How to set up Subversion to support HTTPS?

Tags: svn, https

This may be a FAQ but my attempts at getting a *straightforward answer* from the tigris website failed. All I know is that the admins at our site failed to set up or enable Subversion HTTPS access, and that they claim that WebDAV would be needed for that, but they haven't set that up either.

What's the real low down?

Thanks.

Comment: Correct, WebDAV HTTP verbs are used by Subversion clients when they connect to a server over HTTP or HTTPS protocols.  It's fairly straightforward to configure in Apache with the mod_dav_svn module.  Can you provide more details about the setup?  Generally speaking, the people directly managing the system should be asking these questions - you could send them to us ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've created an HTTPS: oriented production Subversion server at a previous company with no problems and I don't recall doing anything with WebDAV.

You can start with the Tigris Subversion packages using HTTP: and then fairly easily convert it to HTTPS: using steps just like any normally configured HTTPS: website.  Nothing special that I remember.